# Duplicate Symbol Error When trying to Compile Fortran Code

Tags: macos, linker, fortran, ld, gfortran

I'm trying to compile several Fortran subroutines in addition to a main program and block data file on a Macbook Air (Big Sur 11.6). I'm using gfortran with the specific flag,

```
gfortran -L/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib  *.f08
```

Currently using the -L flag is the only way I can get most Fortran compilations to work from now on.

The error that I get after using the above compilation command is

```
duplicate symbol '_reals_' in:
/var/folders/rt/z3gtmqkn3zsg9n2x0pm6jw200000gn/T//ccXBiLt3.o
/var/folders/rt/z3gtmqkn3zsg9n2x0pm6jw200000gn/T//ccC8EISk.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using GNU Fortran 11.1.0

I suspect the two problem causing Fortran files in the collection that I'm trying to compile are the block data file, block_data.f08, and ssivel.f08, both below. The code is the Fortran77 examples included in the appendices of the book, 'Molecular Dynamics Simulation: Elementary Methods', by J.M. Haile.

```
        subroutine ssivel
      2 implicit real*8 (a-h, o-z)
      3 
      4    real*4 roulet
      5    common /intgrs/ ints(7)
      6    common /reals/ rl(26)
      7    common /vel/ x1(256), y1(256), z1(256)
      8 
      9    equivalence (ints(4), natom)
     10    equivalence (rl(9), fnatom), (rl(23), velsq)
     11 
     12    data sumx, sumy, sumz, velsq /4*0.d0/
     13    mseed = -30509
     14 
     15 !...assign random velocity components on (-1, +1); roulet is given in appendix h
     16    do 100 i = 1, natom
     17       x1(i) = roulet(mseed)
     18       y1(i) = roulet(mseed)
     19       z1(i) = roulet(mseed)
     20       sumx = sumx + x1(i)
     21       sumy = sumy + y1(i)
     22       sumz = sumz + z1(i)
     23 100 continue
     24 
     25 !...scale velocities so that total linear momentum is zero; see eq. (5.28)
     26    do 120 i = 1, natom
     27       x1(i) = x1(i) - sumx/fnatom
     28       y1(i) = y1(i) - sumy/fnatom
     29       z1(i) = z1(i) - sumz/fnatom
     30       velsq = velsq + x1(i)**2 + y1(i)**2 + z1(i)**2
     31 120 continue
     32 
     33 !...scale velocities to set-point temperature or to set-point total energy
     34    call sscale(0.)
     35    return
```

```
        block data
      2 implicit real*8(a-h, o-z)
      3 
      4    common /deriv3/ x3(256), y3(256), z3(256)
      5    common /deriv4/ x4(256), y4(256), z4(256)
      6    common /deriv5/ x5(256), y5(256), z5(256)
      7    common /force/ fx(256), fy(256), fz(256)
      8    common /nablst/ list(15000), npoint(256)
      9    common /rdf/ ngofr(300), gr(300)
     10    common /reals/ rl(26)
     11 
     12    equivalence (rl(17), sumenr),(rl(18),sumvir),(rl(19), sumvsq)
     13 
     14    data x3/256*0.d0/,y3/256*0.d0/,z3/256*0.d0/
     15    data x4/256*0.d0/,y4/256*0.d0/,z4/256*0.d0/
     16    data x5/256*0.d0/,y5/256*0.d0/,z5/256*0.d0/
     17    data fx/256*0.d0/,fy/256*0.d0/,fz/256*0.d0/
     18    data ngofr/300*0/
     19    data list/15000*0/, npoint/256*0/
     20    data sumenr, sumvir, sumvsq/3*0.d0/
     21 
     22    end
```

Comment: Have you got 2 block data segments with the same common blocks?

Comment: No, the Block Data segment in the separate file block_data.f08 is the only block data segment. However, there are 'data statemens' in other routines such as roulet.f08 (not listed), and the sole data statement in subroutine ssivel.f08 shown above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a restriction on block data, that you might not be aware of:

> The same labeled common block cannot be specified in more than one block data subprogram in the same executable program.

i.e.:

```
equivalence (rl(9), fnatom), (rl(23), velsq)

data sumx, sumy, sumz, velsq /4*0.d0/
```

and

```
   12    equivalence (rl(17), sumenr),(rl(18),sumvir),(rl(19), sumvsq)
[...]
   20    data sumenr, sumvir, sumvsq/3*0.d0/
```

both try to initialize the reals common block which is disallowed.

Comment: To be very nitpicking - we do not have two block data subprograms here. We have one block data and one data statement in a regular subroutine.

Comment: True, but the effect is the same: defining variables moves them or the enclosing common block from the bss to the data section and symbols in the data segment can only be defined by one data section entry.